# Charis and charisma

Tags: spiritual-gifts, grace

The word for grace is "charis" χάρις, which is the root word for gifts in 1 Cor 12:4 "charisma" χάρισμα. Question: if charis means grace, what does "ma" mean in the word charisma?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different from others.

Answer (score 3):

The suffix -μα has several meanings, but it can be understood in one sense as the product or result of the action of its associated verb.

According to Carl Darling Buck,<sup>1</sup>

> *Neuters.*—G. *-μα*, gen. *-ματος* (250), L. *-men*. Originally action nouns, but most frequently denoting the result of the action. One of the most productive types in Greek, the number running to several thousands.

For example, the verb γράφω means “to write”, and γράμμα is the result of writing, i.e., a writing or letter. Again, νοέω means “to think”, and νόημα means “thought”. Likewise, χαρίζομαι can mean “to give freely”, and **χάρισμα** is the thing that is given freely, i.e., **the gift**.

Eckhard J. Schnabel writes,<sup>2</sup>

> (a) The noun χάρισμα is derived from the verb χαρίζεσθαι (to give freely as a favor). (b) The ending -μα marks the noun as a result noun (*nomen rei actae*; HvS §362c); that is, χάρισμα describes the result of the action implied in the verb, not an event..., meaning “that which is freeely and graciously given” (BDAG).

---

| Footnotes |
| --- |
| <sup>1</sup> Buck, p. [320](https://archive.org/details/BuckComparativeGrammer/page/n335/mode/2up?view=theater) <sup>2</sup> Schnabel, p. [83](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z3quEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA83-IA15#v=onepage&q&f=false) |

| References |
| --- |
| Buck, Carl Darling. [*Comparative Grammar of Greek and Latin.*](https://archive.org/details/BuckComparativeGrammer) Chicago: U of Chicago P, 1933. Schnabel, Eckhard J. [*New Testament Theology.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z3quEAAAQBAJ) Grand Rapids: Baker Academic, 2023. |

Comment: +1. Good answer.  "krima" is another good example as distinct from "krisis".